# how to qsub jobs to the cluster from the parent directory for the subdirectories

Tags: linux, qsub

I have difficulties in submitting my jobs from the parent directory in Linux. Assume that in my parent directory, I do have 1000 sub directories named 1,2,3 ...., 1000 in all of which there is a submission script submit.sh. 
Rather than going to each subdirectory and qsub individually which of course takes a huge time of mine, I need to qsub all scripts from the parent directory such that all calculations and outputs will be dumped out in the corresponding subdirectoy. is there any way to do so?

I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

How about a shell script?

If you just need to run each `submit.sh`, then this should do what you're asking in `bash`:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
  cd "$i"
  ./submit.sh
  cd ..
done
```

Or if you need to pass them as an argument to something, e.g. `qsub`, then just add whatever you need, for example:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
  cd "$i"
  qsub submit.sh
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: I think the OP might be looking for more like `cd $i; ./submit.sh; cd ..` inside the loop, to ensure that each script is run with the subdirectory as the working directory.

Comment: Edited to add. Thanks!